# error: passing 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'

Tags: c, cs50

I'm working on a greedy algorithm where I am getting an error while converting float to int

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float n;
    //checking if given input is valid or not
    do
    {
        n = get_float();
    }
    while(n<0);
    //converting dollar into cents
    float coins = n * 100;

     int x = atoi(coins) //getting error here???

....
}
```

Comment: As a general principle, in the vast majority of C programs, you really want to use `double` instead of `float`.  But that isn't relevant to your error.

Answer (score 2):

The `atoi` function is used to convert a string into an integer.  It expects a `char *` as an argument which points to a string.

You don't need a conversion function here.  You can assign a `float` value directly to an `int`, and any fractional part will be truncated.

```
int x = coins;
```

Note however that this can invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the truncated value of `coins` is outside the range of an `int`.

Comment: This answer may really need an extra note that this potentially may be an UB if `coins` value does not fit `int`.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` converts ascii to integer, and a `float` isn't an `int`. Check the function definition in the header file. I suggest using `atof()` instead, or perhaps `strtod()`.

Comment: In context, the program doesn't want to convert a string to a number at all, so none of these functions are relevant.  It wants to convert a `float` to an `int` so a simple assignment or cast suffices.

Comment: @NateEldredge an assignment + check if the value can be represented by `int` perhaps